# Date filter does not show data

Tags: vba, date, filter

I want to make macro, that filter table by date. Everything is OK, except for that it does not show data after filter. But when I manually look to the column, filter set is right and after I click "OK button" the data will be displayed. Below is my code. Thanks for help :)

```
 Sub Filter ()
    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate= InputBox("Your date? (Format 00.00.0000)")

    Range("C1").AutoFilter
            Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=01.01.2018", _
            Criteria2:="<=" & myDate
            'I also tried "Format([myDate], "dd-mm-yyyy")"

End sub
```

Comment: You'll need to use a standard Excel date format.  See [The Definitive Guide to Using Dates and Times in Excel](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-using-dates-times-excel/) and [How to use dates and times in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel) and [How to Convert Numbers to Dates in Excel](https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-Convert-an-Excel-Number-to-Date).

Comment: Ashleedawg, Thanks for help. Now its work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering a range with one cell, you have only 1 field on it. And not 3:

```
Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=01.01.2018", Criteria2:="<=" & myDate
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried change "Range" and "Field", but still not working (showing data).